# Rails 3.1 named routes query params issue from presenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

After upgrading an app from Rails 3.0.17 to 3.1.8 I've come across a strange error with a using a named route and adding query params.

Starting backwards, here's the relevant error and stacktrace:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `env' for #<AnswerPagesPresenter:0x0000000420df60>):
  actionpack (3.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/url_for.rb:36:in `url_options'
  actionpack (3.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:148:in `url_for'
  actionpack (3.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:207:in `edit_answer_sheet_page_path'
  vendor/plugins/questionnaire_engine/app/presenters/answer_pages_presenter.rb:81:in `new_page_link'
  vendor/plugins/questionnaire_engine/app/presenters/answer_pages_presenter.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in page_list'
  vendor/plugins/questionnaire_engine/app/presenters/answer_pages_presenter.rb:90:in `each'
  vendor/plugins/questionnaire_engine/app/presenters/answer_pages_presenter.rb:90:in `block in page_list'
  vendor/plugins/questionnaire_engine/app/presenters/answer_pages_presenter.rb:89:in `each'
  vendor/plugins/questionnaire_engine/app/presenters/answer_pages_presenter.rb:89:in `page_list'
  vendor/plugins/questionnaire_engine/app/presenters/answer_pages_presenter.rb:21:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/applications_controller.rb:166:in `new'
  app/controllers/applications_controller.rb:166:in `setup_view'
  app/controllers/applications_controller.rb:19:in `show_default'
...
```

Here's the piece of code in AnswerPagesPresenter that is calling the named route (I've tried using mulitple things for the 'a' variable, which is the extra query param, but it's nil normally):

```
def new_page_link(answer_sheet, page, a = nil)
  PageLink.new(page.label, edit_answer_sheet_page_path(answer_sheet, page, :a => a), dom_page(answer_sheet, page), page) if page
end
```

Also at the top of my Presenter class I have the following lines of code:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper # link_to
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper # url_for
include ActionController::UrlFor # named routes
include ActionController::RecordIdentifier # dom_id
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

And the relevant line from running the 'rake routes' command just to show it's a valid route:

```
edit_answer_sheet_page GET    /answer_sheets/:answer_sheet_id/page/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"answer_pages"}
```

From the routes.rb file in the plugin:

```
resources :answer_sheets do 
  member do
    post :send_reference_invite
    post :submit
  end
  resources :page, :controller => :answer_pages do
    member do
      post :save_file
    end
  end
end
```

Anyone know what's going on here?  I've tried to figure out why it's going to lib/action_controller/metal/url_for.rb instead of just using the url_options method in lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb, but I'm pretty clueless when it comes to the Rails source code.  This was working just fine in Rails 3.0.17.  I'd appreciate any insights!

Comment: how do you expose the url_helper methods to your presenter?

Comment: @gregates I added the relevant lines to the question, although I did figure out a solution, as you can see. :)

Comment: Cool. Yeah, where I was going was that normally the pattern I've seen is to initialize the presenter with a Helper object stored in an instance variable (usually @h), and then url helpers are invoked by `h.url_helper`, since the helper has access to the request, env, etc. So that's probably an alternate solution.

Comment: @gregates Interesting.  Do you know of anywhere online I could find an example of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was after looking at this commit https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/233be6572c96087192885924c6658a15d01a2a1b#actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/url_for.rb

Apparently if you call a named route from a controller, you'll be fine, since env is already defined.  But if you call it from something else, env isn't defined, and you'll have to define it yourself.  Since it's being called from a self-written presenter (which contains a reference to a controller), I just wrote the following method in Presenter (superclass of AnswerPagesPresenter) and it works now:

```
def env
  @controller.env
end
```